# dpkg error when running sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, kali-linux, dpkg

```
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/587 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error processing package tk8.6-blt2.5 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-tk:
 python-tk depends on tk8.6-blt2.5 (>= 2.5.3); however:
  Package tk8.6-blt2.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-tk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of blt:
 blt depends on tk8.6-blt2.5 (= 2.5.3+dfsg-4); however:
  Package tk8.6-blt2.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package blt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tcpwatch-httpproxy:
 tcpwatch-httpproxy depends on python-tk; however:
  Package python-tk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tcpwatch-httpproxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pil.imagetk:amd64:
 python-pil.imagetk:amd64 depends on python-tk (>= 2.7.7-2); however:
  Package python-tk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pil.imagetk:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tk8.6-blt2.5
 python-tk
 blt
 tcpwatch-httpproxy
 python-pil.imagetk:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@kali:~#
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: How did you get to this situation?

Comment: Do not edit your sources.list and only use Kali repository. Kali is it's own boss, and do not accept easily package from other distribution. Do not use Kali as a main OS, and do not try to install stuff outside its repo except if you PERFECTLY know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important error message is

> `dpkg`: error processing package `tk8.6-blt2.5` (`--configure`): package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration

You need to reinstall that package:

```
apt install --reinstall tk8.6-blt2.5
```